# How to get the previous or next two entries

Tags: templating, craft3

I have an entry which needs to display the previous two entries, and the next two. I see in the docs there's a `nextSiblingOf` method. That does nothing in a channel, and in a structure it will only return one entry. I can't see an ability to "offset" the result.

1: Is this possible in a channel

2: What do I need to do to grab the previous/next two entries in either case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a channel this would be the next entries where the post date is before and after the current entry’s post date. The element queries for it would look like so:

```
{% set query = craft.entries
    .section('blog')
    .id('not ' ~ entry.id)
    .limit(2) %}

{% set prevEntries = clone(query)
    .postDate('<= ' ~ entry.postDate.timestamp)
    .order('postDate desc')
    .all() %}

{% set nextEntries = clone(query)
    .postDate('>= ' ~ entry.postDate.timestamp)
    .order('postDate asc')
    .all() %}
```

If your sort the entries by title, something like this should work:

```
{% set prevEntries = clone(query)
    .title('<= ' ~ entry.title)
    .order('title desc')
    .all() %}

{% set nextEntries = clone(query)
    .title('>= ' ~ entry.title)
    .order('title asc')
    .all() %}
```

Comment: Thanks Christian - looks like maybe I should change the type. The primary way this data is going to be displayed is alphabetically. For some reason I thought "It should be a structure, because they won't be able to re-order them", but perhaps it should be a Structure after all?

Comment: A channel is probably the right section type if you don’t need manual sort order. I just updated the answer and added an example for alphabetically ordered entries.