# In Craft 3 how do I find the title of the previous and next entry when looping through a channel?

Tags: craft3

```
{# Set parameters for prev/next elements list #}
{% set params = craft.entries.section('nieuws').all() %}

{# Get the prev/next elements #}
{% set nextEntry = entry.getNext(params) %}
```

This used to work in Craft 2 in v3 I get an unknown property error. I can retrieve the prev and next links via the paginate tag but how do I retrieve the titles of the prev and next entry??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did is passing array of entries into `getNext` method. You need to pass **array of query criteria** instead:

```
{% set criteria = {section: 'nieuws', order: 'postDate'} %}
{% set prevEntry = entry.getPrev(criteria) %}
```

Note that if there is no next or previous entry, `getPrev` or `getNext` will return `null`.

Answer (score 2):

This did the trick - I'm assuming a news channel here with datestamped entries.

```
{% set query = craft.entries
    .section('nieuws')
    .id('not ' ~ entry.id)
    .limit(1) %}

{% set prevEntry = clone(query)
    .postDate('<= ' ~ entry.postDate.timestamp)
    .order('postDate desc')
    .one() %}

{% set nextEntry = clone(query)
    .postDate('>= ' ~ entry.postDate.timestamp)
    .order('postDate asc')
    .one() %}

{% if prevEntry %}
  <p><a href="{{ prevEntry.url }}">< {{ prevEntry.title }}</a></p>
{% endif %}

{% if nextEntry %}
  <p><a href="{{ nextEntry.url }}">{{ nextEntry.title }} ></a></p>
{% endif %}
```

Hat tip to [How to get the previous or next two entries](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/27269/how-to-get-the-previous-or-next-two-entries)