# How to get the previous or next two entries with images and

Tags: templating, craft3

To expand upon [How to get the previous or next two entries](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/27269/how-to-get-the-previous-or-next-two-entries?answertab=active#tab-top) I was wondering how I can also add the image and an input from each entry.

I have simplified the html-structure in this example but essentially what I want to add is:
entry.portfolioImage.one and row.kundenavn from row in entry.kunde.

The links and entry title is working.

```
{# Set parameters for prev/next elements list #}
{% set params = craft.entries.section('portfolio').order('title desc') %}

{# Get the prev/next elements #}
{% set prevEntry = entry.getPrev(params) %}
{% set nextEntry = entry.getNext(params) %}

{# And make sure to only output the links if the element exists #}
{% if prevEntry %}
  <a class="project" data-type="image" href="{{ prevEntry.url }}">
    <img
      src="{{ entry.portfolioImage.one().getUrl('progressivePortfolio') }}"
      data-src="{{ entry.portfolioImage.one().getUrl() }}"
    >
    <h3>{{ prevEntry.title }}</h3>
    <div class="project-client pink bold">
      {% for row in entry.kunde %}
          {{ row.kundenavn }}
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </a>
{% endif %}
{% if nextEntry %}
  <a class="project" data-type="image" href="{{ nextEntry.url }}">
    <img
      src="{{ entry.portfolioImage.one().getUrl('progressivePortfolio') }}"
      data-src="{{ entry.portfolioImage.one().getUrl() }}"
    >
    <h3>{{ nextEntry.title }}</h3>
    <div class="project-client pink bold">
      {% for row in entry.kunde %}
          {{ row.kundenavn }}
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </a>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bratvold, what do you mean with "input"?

Actually, if you can get the title of your prev-item, you can get everything of it.

```
{% if prevEntry %}
  <a class="project" data-type="image" href="{{ prevEntry.url }}">
    <img
      src="{{ prevEntry.portfolioImage.one().getUrl('progressivePortfolio') }}"
      data-src="{{ prevEntry.portfolioImage.one().getUrl() }}"
    >
    <h3>{{ prevEntry.title }}</h3>
    <div class="project-client pink bold">
      {% for row in prevEntry.kunde.all() %}
          {{ row.kundenavn }}
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! prevEntry worked great for the images but not the other part. This part comes up empty:
```{% for row in prevEntry.kunde.all() %}
    {{ row.kundenavn }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What type of field is ``kunde``? Matrix? Table?

Comment: If "kundenavn" is an entries selection field, you need to loop again. 

`{% for entry in row.kundenavn %}{{ entry.title }}{% endfor %}`

Comment: Thanks @MartenBrosch :)